# How to make a custom dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I want to make a custom alert dialog such as this image
what i will do to make that ?
**i want to design this dialog**[Alert Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGAFo.png)

Comment: what have you done so far ? Where is your code ?

Comment: i want to design this dialog and i have no idea how to design it

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to create a new layout xml file and a new layout for your title if you want custom title also.

```
 final AlertDialog dialog;

    final View alertDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate
            (R.layout.your_layout, null);
    final View titleView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

 dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setView(alertDialogView)
            .setCustomTitle(titleView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.set, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  ///do your job
            })
            .setCancelable(true)
            .create();


    dialog.show();
```

also if you want to access the title from custom layout you can access it in this way:

```
((TextView) titleView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getString(R.string.
your_string));
```

Comment: i don't have any problems in implementation